# Journals with double-blind peer review process

Tags: reference-request, big-list, publishing

I apologize if this site is not the right place to ask this question. I could not find an answer elsewhere.

Some journals like **The American Mathematical Monthly** or  **Mathematics Magazine** implement a double-blind review system.

(1) In there an available list of similar mathematical journals which implement a double-blind review system.

(2) Do you know any other mathematical journal which implements a double-blind review system?

Comment: Since I don't know of any, I am not leaving this as an answer. But the AMM is special in that it does not (usually) publish regular research papers. Any "normal" journal will be in for a Sisyphean task trying to make it work, as essentially all papers will already be on the arXiv, and reviewers who are sufficiently familiar with the field to be qualified to review it will likely have already seen it there.

Comment: If you google "double-blind mathematics -experiment -study" you can find a few of these